# Issue with deploying Angular Universal app with Angular Fire on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, google-cloud-run, angular-universal

I'm currently facing an issue while deploying my Angular Universal app with Angular Fire on Firebase. I have followed the official Angular Universal documentation and the new Firebase web frameworks guide, but I'm not getting the expected result when running ng deploy or firebase deploy.

Here are the details of my setup:

- **Angular version**: v16.1
- **Angular Universal version**: v16.1
- **Angular Fire version**: v7.6.1
- **Repository**: https://github.com/plungarini/lungabros

---

When I check the Firebase deploy logs, I see the following error message:

```
hosting[lungabros]: Unable to find a valid endpoint for function `ssrlungabros`, but still including it in the config
It seems that the server-side rendering (SSR) function is not being generated properly. I have also noticed that the function is not visible in the "Functions" tab or the "Google Run" tab in the Google Cloud console.
```

I have already double-checked my Angular Universal configuration and Firebase configuration, ensuring that I have followed all the required steps and dependencies.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently setting "minInstances" to 1 in my firebase.json inside "frameworksBackend" options, fixed the ssr function deployment.

#### Update:

Actually you'll have to use `firebase deploy` rather than `ng deploy`. This solves the issue. Is not a minInstances config.